# Program will not stop when the conditions are passed

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, sum, triplet

I'm writing a sum up game where two players will take turns picking a random number in the range (1,9), no repeated number allowed. If the first player picks [7, 2, 3, 5], he will win because 7+3+5 = 15

So my question is why doesn't the program stop when first_player has a sum of inputs that == 15
Below is the readme file

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: if you don't know how to use debugger then use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging"

Answer (score 0):

Your script is too verbose. If you made it more dynamic, with reusable logic, it becomes much easier to work with. I rewrote your game as an example.

**notes:**

- All the game states are reused in `fstrings`, as `dict` keys, and even to represent the player
- The game loop (`update()`) represents a single turn, and the player that turn corresponds to is toggled at the end of the loop
- `make_move` also represents one turn
- the entire game is contained in the class
- `reset()` is used to clear the window, reset all the game properties, and start the loop, but the very first time it is called it acts as an initializer for all of the game properties.
- There is never going to be an instance where both players have 15 points

---

```
import os

UNFINISHED  = "unfinished"
DRAW        = "draw"
FIRST_WON   = "First"
SECOND_WON  = "Second"

CLEAR       = lambda: os.system('cls') #windows only

class AddThreeGame:
    @property
    def current_state(self):
        return self.__state
        
    @property
    def player(self):
        return self.__rotation[self.__player]

    def __init__(self):
        self.__rotation = [FIRST_WON, SECOND_WON]
        self.__states = {
            UNFINISHED:'We have unfinished business, come back for more\n',
            DRAW:'Draw game\n',
            FIRST_WON:'First player won this game!!!\n',
            SECOND_WON:'Second player won this game!!!\n',
        }
        
        self.reset()
    
    def make_move(self, player, number):
        if number not in range(1, 10) or number in self.__input:
            return False
            
        self.__input.append(number)
        self.__players[self.player].append(number)
        
        if len(self.__players[self.player]) >= 3:
            L = self.__players[self.player]
            for i in range(0, len(L)-2):
                for j in range(i+1, len(L)-1):
                    for k in range(j+1, len(L)):
                        if (L[i] + L[j] + L[k]) == 15:
                            self.__state = player
                            return True
    
        if len(self.__input) == 9:
            self.__state = DRAW
    
        return True
        
    def update(self):
        while True:
            num = int(input(f'{self.player} player please enter a number from 1 to 9: '))
            while True:
                if self.make_move(self.player, num):
                    break
                else:
                    num = int(input("Wrong input, please try a different number: "))
                    
            if self.current_state == UNFINISHED:
                if self.__player == 1: #technically, this is player 2
                    print(self.__states[self.current_state])
                #next player
                self.__player = (self.__player + 1) % 2
            else:
                print(self.__states[self.current_state])
                break

        
        if input('Play Again? (y or n): ') == 'y':        
            self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
        CLEAR()
        self.__player = 0
        self.__input  = []
        self.__state  = UNFINISHED
        
        self.__players = {
            FIRST_WON:[],
            SECOND_WON:[],
        }
        self.update()

  
if __name__ == '__main__':      
    AddThreeGame()
```

Answer (score 0):

The game doesn't stop when first player's inputs equal 15 because you ask for second player's input regardless of whether the first player won. You can see this in your testing code, where you have two `while` statements for each player's input. If you complete that round with second player's input, your program works and stops there. To stop when a player wins on input, just add the conditional check to break out of main loop before asking for next player's input.